# pretty print XML file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom, java-8

### Original Question

I'm trying to prettyprint an XML-file without any external libraries, but cannot get Java to do what I want... Here is my code so far (I added any solutions from similar questions!):

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
tfactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 4);
Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.MEDIA_TYPE, "text/xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xalan}indent-amount", "4");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputPropertiesFactory.S_KEY_INDENT_AMOUNT, "4");
File file = new File("C:\\text.xml");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(file));
transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(file));
```

Having an input file looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><root><test><item0>a</item0><item1>b</item1></test></root>
```

I receive an output looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>

<test>
<item0>a</item0>
<item1>b</item1>
    </test>
</root>
```

Now the thing I don't get is why there is a blank line after `<root>` and an indentation before `</test>`, but nowhere else. Running the code on this new file changes nothing!

I would like my output file to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <test>
        <item0>a</item0>
        <item1>b</item1>
     </test>
 </root>
```

---

### Update

I have removed some lines from my code that apparently weren't doing anything anyway:

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
tfactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 4);
Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xalan}indent-amount", "4");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
File file = new File("C:\\text.xml");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(file));
transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(file));
```

This now creates a pretty printed file from the one-line-file from the original question, so that part of the question is answered! I don't know what exactly the problem was, but whatever, works now^^

But I also have some old files that are read from and written to by my program that look kind of like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
<test>
<item0>a</item0>
<item1>b</item1>
</test>
</root>
```

They have a line break after every node, but no indentation. My code leaves the file unchanged... How do I correct this?

Comment: What is the class of `tfactory` when you run your code? What JDK do you use?

Comment: tfactory is of type javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory and I use 1.8.0_66-b18 (released on 11.11.2015)

Comment: and what is the implementation class of `tfactory`, i.e. when you print `System.out.println(tfactory.getClass())`

Comment: class com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl

Comment: strange, using JDK 1.8.0_45 (which has the same transformer implementation) I get a nice looking indented output when running your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tagged this XSLT, and if you apply the following XSLT stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to your XML input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <test>
        <item0>a</item0>
        <item1>b</item1>
    </test>
</root>
```

Live demo: http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mg

Note that the items are "pretty printed" as:

```
<item0>a</item0>
```

and not as shown in your post:

```
<item0>
    a
</item0>
```

which would represent a change in the content payload of the XML.

Comment: fixed content mismatch in the question

Comment: @user2336377 Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with complex and error-prone Java code , when you can **simply transform with [the identity rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying)**, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><root><test><item0>a</item0><item1>b</item1></test></root>
```

**A pretty, and more importantly uniform (per XSLT processor) output is produced**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <test>
      <item0>a</item0>
      <item1>b</item1>
   </test>
</root>
```

Comment: This will not be the result when using the Xalan processor (as OP obviously does) - see: http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mg/1